# How can I convert .pptx slides to images with php?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, powerpoint

I have a problem with mine project. I am building a website, where I can show .pptx presentations with php and xml. I would like to show thumbnails of each slide. I am not using images on the site, but getting values from xml and saving the data in the database.

I would like to show thumbnails on cms of each slides from project(.pptx project).

Is it possible do this with php? I am uploading and convert/unpack zip for the xml version but how can I do this for the images.

Comment: It's not impossible, but is certainly non-trivial.... even just being able to read a pptx file is complex.... you might take a look at [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/tree/develop/src/PhpPresentation) as a starting point for reading Powerpoint files

Comment: Also look into the office open xml schema, maybe there's something you can leverage

Comment: PHPPresentation is for creating slides. I would like to save slides of a .pptx file as an image .jpg/png.

Comment: Office open xml is for c#/.net and not for php.